# vb.net RegEX number and letter with period format

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hey all I am trying to find a **REGEX** that will allow me to find these types of numbers/letters in this formats:

> XX.XXX

Example: DT.3 or SV.32 or TF.1

> XXXX.XXX

Example: 8920.17 or 8477.1 or 1699.22

Can anyone lend a helping hand?

Comment: http://regexr.com/ is a free web tool which makes it simple to develop regex's. As for what you're after you'll need to be more specific about what is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: Try `[0-9A-Z]+\.[0-9]+`. If length is fixed try `(?:[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{2})[0-9]{1,3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First format - `([A-Z]{2}\.[0-9]{1,2})`

https://regex101.com/r/iT1eG6/1

Second format - `([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,2})`

https://regex101.com/r/pS7bC0/2

Combined - `((?:[A-Z]{2}\.[0-9]{1,2})|(?:([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,2})))`

https://regex101.com/r/kN6tV0/1

Regex101 breaks up the regex and explains every part. So if you need to, customise the regex further according to your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to place both of those into just one?

Comment: yes `((?:[A-Z]{2}\.[0-9]{1,2})|(?:([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,2})))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Charsi